# Why a Windows process loads its own exe images for multiple times?

Tags: windows, etw

all

I'm doing a security related project which need to record the image loads events of each process.

I found a strange thing: a process always loads its own executible file for multiple times.

[image: A process loads its own executible file for multiple times]

I don't know why. As far as I can see, images with a same path can only be loaded once.

So I checked the call stacks of these events by using Process Monitor(a tool from Windows SysInternal), the callstacks are different. But I have no idea how to explain it. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

[image: Different callstacks of image load]

Comment: An image can be loaded as a datafile, too.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry. I don't understand. If the file is loaded as an image(a library), it could only be loaded once. And if it is loaded as a datafile, I don't think it would generate such a Load Image Event. Could you explain it a little more?  Thanks.

Comment: "Image load event. Generated when a DLL or executable file is loaded. The provider generates only one event for the first time a given DLL is loaded."  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/ETW/image)

Comment: The documentation is noting that two calls to LoadLibrary result in the module being loaded only once. But as is evident from the stack trace, there are other things that can load a module, such as creating an activation context. (You can see that it's not the same load because the addresses are different.)